# Is there any way to initialize an array of text views in java android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I have seven text views (textview0....textview6) in my xml file and in my java file I want to loop through these views but I faced a problem that I can't use the findViewById function because I can't use the index (i) in the name
I want something similar to this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<=6 ;i++){
textview[i] = findViewById(R.id.textview+i)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<=6 ;i++) {
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("textview"+ i, "id", this.getPackageName());
    textview[i] = findViewById(resourceId);
}
```

Comment: Use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code.